# set the model on the center of the scene in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

am using the following code to visualize the object on the center of the scene, it is working fine for the json loder, if we use `OBJLoder` or `OBJMTLloder` it is not working

```
function modelLoadedCallback(geometry, materials) {

    /* create the object from the geometry and materials that were loaded.  There
       can be multiple materials, which can be applied to the object using MeshFaceMaterials.
       Note tha the material can include references to texture images might finish
       loading later. */

    var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));

    /* Determine the ranges of x, y, and z in the vertices of the geometry. */

    var xmin = Infinity;
    var xmax = -Infinity;
    var ymin = Infinity;
    var ymax = -Infinity;
    var zmin = Infinity;
    var zmax = -Infinity;
    for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
        var v = geometry.vertices[i];
        if (v.x < xmin)
            xmin = v.x;
        else if (v.x > xmax)
            xmax = v.x;
        if (v.y < ymin)
            ymin = v.y;
        else if (v.y > ymax)
            ymax = v.y;
        if (v.z < zmin)
            zmin = v.z;
        else if (v.z > zmax)
            zmax = v.z;
    }

    /* translate the center of the object to the origin */
    var centerX = (xmin+xmax)/2;
    var centerY = (ymin+ymax)/2; 
    var centerZ = (zmin+zmax)/2;
    var max = Math.max(centerX - xmin, xmax - centerX);
    max = Math.max(max, Math.max(centerY - ymin, ymax - centerY) );
    max = Math.max(max, Math.max(centerZ - zmin, zmax - centerZ) );
    var scale = 10/max;
    object.position.set( -centerX, -centerY, -centerZ );
    console.log("Loading finished, scaling object by " + scale);
    console.log("Center at ( " + centerX + ", " + centerY + ", " + centerZ + " )");

    /* Create the wrapper, model, to scale and rotate the object. */

    model = new THREE.Object3D();
    model.add(object);
    model.scale.set(scale,scale,scale);
    rotateX = rotateY = 0;
    scene.add(model);
    render();

}
```

it causing `TypeError: s is undefined`, so my model is not showing on the scene, what is wrong here?? there is any other method avail to center the object with `OBJLoder` or `OBJMTLloder`

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to go through the vertices of your model to figure out its center. There is a `geometry.computeBoundingBox()` method you can use to compute the bounding box of your geometry. Take a look at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry.

For a Geometry node you should be able to do:

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox ();
var bBox = geometry.boundingBox;
alert('bounding box coordinates: ' + 
    '(' + bBox.min.x + ', ' + bBox.min.y + ', ' + bBox.min.z + '), ' + 
    '(' + bBox.max.x + ', ' + bBox.max.y + ', ' + bBox.max.z + ')' );
```

Comment: if i compute as like u said here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d, everything is as `Nan`, what is wrong here ??

Comment: no, now it alerting `bounding box coordinates: (Infinity, Infinity, Infinity), (-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity)`, but am missing my object from the scene

Comment: Without posting the geometry that produces this result, I cannot help. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, i have created fiddle but that is not working, can you check it here http://3dmodelviewer.osiztechnologies.com/threejs/examples/wireframe.php please

Comment: Look at your code. You are calling computeBoundingBox on a geometry outside the traverse. The value of the geometry variable is the last thing that was traversed. What you need to do there is call `BoundingBoxHelper ( object, 0x00ffff )` to see the bounding box of your `object`.

Comment: Hi @gaitat, please refer the screenshot of my object `BoundingBoxHelper`,http://3dmodelviewer.osiztechnologies.com/threejs/examples/boundingbox.png,

Comment: sure, you can check it here the updated code http://3dmodelviewer.osiztechnologies.com/threejs/examples/wireframe.php

Comment: You are passing `mesh` to `BoundingBoxHelper`. You should be passing `object`.

Comment: Than u so much for your effort, i have passed `object` instead of `mesh`, still am getting same result

Comment: In this case the call to `BoundingBoxHelper` should be inside the `object.traverse` call. Do not forget that model loading is asynchronous. At the place that you have called `BoundingBoxHelper` the `object` is not loaded yet.

Comment: hi @gaitat yes am calling `BoundingBoxHelper` inside the `object.traverse`, and i can't understand what you are saying as asynchronous,?? anything am doing wrong here??

Comment: Hi @gaitat, have any reply to me ??

Comment: `BoundingBoxHelper` should be called outside the `object.traverse()` with the first argument being `object` but only when the model has loaded completely (because loading of the model is asynchronous).

Comment: ok, i called `BoundingBoxHelper` outside `object.traverse()` but still i can't see any changes on the BoundingBox

Comment: also do u have any answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512312/how-to-add-reflectionmaterial-for-an-object-in-threejs question

Comment: You also need to do what this post says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775687/three-js-wrong-bounding-box-importing-blender-json-model

Comment: you are my master, now i can see the `BoundingBoxHelper` around my object, however i set my `camera.position.z = 100;` so the object doesn't centered on the scene, what i have to do now?? there is no way to set the loading objects on the center of the scene?? am being trying this from last 2 weeks, but no way to get it, thanks again for your help...

Comment: `BoundingBoxHelper`is working but am getting `bbHelper` is undefined on `bbHelper.update();` i have declared `bbHelper` as globally

Comment: can you update the code at your site. I don't see `bbHelper` defined globally. How can it be working if it is undefined?